how can i find A Name of a python skript with excel macros
i have a Python script that needs to be called with a excle macro but i need to find the path just from the name is it possible and whenn how do i do it?
Private Sub button_Click()
Dim vbash As Object

 
    Set vbash = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
     pythonScriptPath = FindPythonScript()
     
    MsgBox "Python-Skript gefunden: " & pythonScriptPath, vbInformation, "Erfolg"

    
    vbash.Run "cmd /c python """ & pythonScriptPath & """"

End Sub

Function FindPythonScript() As String
    Dim Dateinmame As String
    Dim Suchbegriff As String
    Dim Pfad As String
    
    Pfad = "C:\"
    Suchbegriff = "Fulle_word_tamplat"
    
    Dateinmame = Dir(Pfad & "*" & Suchbegriff & "*.py")
    
    If Dateinmame <> "" Then
        FindPythonScript = Pfad & Dateinmame
    Else
        FindPythonScript = ""
    End If
End Function


Well, unless it is installed as a module, you need to KNOW where the script file is.  You can't expect to search the entire disk drive.  Perhaps you need a mini-installer that copies the Excel spreadsheet and the Python helper to a known location.
